# Why Open file Security Warning is so slow for mysetup.exe?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Why opening mysetup.exe takes 30 seconds to open?
The delay occurs also when I click the exe from Explorer and if its inside downloads folder. There is no delay in other folders.

The 30 second delay appears before Windows displays a Security Warning dialog "do you want to run this file?" -  I think delay is related to Open file security Warning / AES?

The other files (same size setuppers) do open immediately within 1-2 seconds after downloading, just this new inno packed software (5 MB file size) takes 30 seconds to open.

The mysetup.exe file is digitally signed (comodo)

Comment: Maybe you have something in Code Section `[Code] function InitializeSetup: Boolean;`?

Comment: Or maybe... you have added some files that are to be upnacked on the Setup Init, but you have added them last in the `Files` section with `SolidCompression=True`. In that case, Setup has to "unpack/check" all files before it will be able to unpack files that have `{tmp}` destination. All files that you want your installer use for the installation process should be added as first and (best solution) with `nocompression` flag. If we could see the code...

Comment: So... if when triggering the download you would select different folder (e.g. C:\), there would not be any lag on running after download? Maybe there are some security rules for Download folder (e.g. AntyVirus Software or System based)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This delay is down to Explorer trying to verify the signature of the entire executable. It happens on all executables but is far more noticable when the size is over a few hundred MB. It will also stop displaying the icon at some point for the same reason.

As this is entirely an Explorer bug, then the only thing you can do in Inno Setup is to split the setup into smaller files using the `DiskSpanning` directive.

Comment: Tom wrote: [...] It does not make difference when unsigned [...]. And [...]just this new inno packed software (5 MB file size) takes 30 seconds to open.[...] - so splitting it to even... smaller... is rather not a good idea :)

Comment: @RobeN It doesn't matter if it's signed or not. Explorer still checks the executable to see if it is or not. The fact that it's a delay BEFORE the Explorer security warning shows that it's not the setup itself as it hasn't even been launched yet (what would be the point of a security check if it had been :)

Comment: But why only this single file (5 MB) causes the problem and no other? Cannot it be fault of the code itself? The Explorer bug selects files somehow where it shows up?

Comment: @RobeN I have no idea why this would happen on a small file, maybe a slow network/drive? It's before it even runs the setup so Inno's code shouldn't come into it at all.

Comment: Tom also writes it happens only in "Downloads" folder - maybe it's system/av related?

Comment: The network is not slow.  Other downloads+installs are OK. The size of my file is 5mb.  AV is microsoft security essentials.

Comment: Notice; I use COMODO  code sign cert,  the problem seem to occur especially with CODE SIGNED file.

Comment: There are two components to signature validation.  One is scanning the entire file to build a hash to verify against the signature -- this is affected by the size of the file, as discussed above.  The other is contacting the vendor of the certificate (Comodo, in this case) to obtain its "revokation list" -- the "valid" certificates that should no longer be honored (for various reasons).  So if you have reduced the size of the file with little effect, your problem is the second.  Either you have a slow internet connection (or maybe a bad proxy) or Comodo has a slow server.

Comment: @Miral Noted. I thought it tried to contact the signing authorities servers for something but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

Also, 30 seconds is a fairly common Internet connection timeout.  So if Windows has a network connection but not an Internet connection (eg. external router turned off or blocking Internet access) then it's probably trying to contact the Comodo servers, but eventually timing out.  (The default behaviour for a timeout is to treat the certificate as valid regardless, as it is assumed that most certificates are valid.)